# AWS elasticsearch url encoding

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I am using AWS elasticsearch and using AWS signature V4 to communicate with the instance.

I tried encoding my URI in following ways:
1] /index1%2Cindex2/type1%2Ctype2/_search

and (Double encoding)

2] /index1%252Cindex2/type1%252Ctype2/_search

Still AWS expects the % to be encoded again as follows.
/index1%25252Cindex2/type1%25252Ctype2/_search

Any help would be appreciated.